# Double monitor duplicate

Tags: virtualbox, multi-monitor

I do have Arch linux on my VirtualBox VM. I use this machine for few specific tasks, where GUI is not requested, so that I did not even install it and, because of performances, I would like to maintain this configuration.

I set up the resolution, usually, at boot time via [Kernel Command Line](http://distro.ibiblio.org/fatdog/web/faqs/boot-options.html), and everything works beautifully.

Now, I would like to add a second monitor, let's say vertical. At this point, this second monitor is a perfect duplicate of the first one. I wonder if, at the present condition, is actually possible to make the two monitors working independently with, for example one different terminal each.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this, you may be better off running `X` with a simple window manager like `i3`, then you can use `xrandr` to configure the screen set up and run a terminal emulator on each screen.